# Firebase Authentication Phone Re-Register

Tags: android, database, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

If once phone number registered and i removed from console that number and again i try to register that time i'm not getting any verification code.

is there any way to get again verification code ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/

You might want to shoot them an email about that, or file a bug report perhaps? Or maybe it's already listed in their FAQ

Comment: You should be getting the verification code again. Make sure your internet connection is available and please post the code here.

Comment: @Einzig7 i'm not getting code again and my number getting register again without verification code.

Comment: How can it be registered without a verification code? Is it that you have implemented auto authentication by any chance?

Comment: @Einzig7 nope, First time i got verification code and then i remove number from console and again i try to test that but that time i didn't get verification code and also i removed test application and installed it again .

Comment: Uninstalling and installing won't make a difference here. Just tell me that when you are trying to register through phone authentication, then are you able to register, or your app crashes or throws any exception?

Comment: @Einzig7 yes i'm able to register.

Comment: And it shows your number in the console as well right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174880/discussion-between-kishan-and-einzig7).

Answer (score 4):

This is not a problem, it's because you are using Instant Verification. You are probably using `onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential)` method in your code, and according to FireBase Documentation:

This method is called in two situations:

1. Instant verification: in some cases, the phone number can be instantly verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
2. Auto-retrieval: on some devices, Google Play services can automatically detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without user action. (This capability might be unavailable with some carriers.)

If you want, you can try this:
For this, you'll need two devices, each with a phone number. Enter the phone number of the other device on the first one and you'll notice that you have received an OTP, this happens because Auto-retrieval isn't taking place this time.

Comment: Please mark the answer correct so that it can help others. Happy Coding :)